# Is it possible to get the forgot password verification code for cognito in node js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want the verification code that is sent to the user email in the callback of forgot password method in cognito. I need the verification code for some other works.
Is this possible?

Or can we add our own custom verification code for Cognito forgotPassword?
It would be of great help if someone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance !!